# Writting columns of data in *.dat file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image]

I want to write specific data, say, after analysis I get in the following fashion shown in the above figure so that whenever requires I can extract any particular column as I wish following the commands:

```py
f= np.loadtxt("Data1.dat", unpack=True)
x = f[0,:]
```

However, I have tried `pd.DataFrame()` but didn't work.

```py
import csv 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
x = [0.11, 2.15, 0.39, 5.79, 6.53]
y = [99.2, -0.32, -12.95, -2.5, -7.5]

n = len(x)
 
#with open('data1.dat', 'w', newline='') as f:  
#   wtr = csv.writer(f)
#   for k in range(n):
#       wtr.writerow([x[k], y[k]])
  
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
df.to_csv('data1.dat')
```

Comment: When saving the dataframe as `csv` try to use `df.to_csv('data1.dat', index=False, sep=' ', header=None)`. This will remove the `index`, `header` and use `space` as the separator. This way `numpy` `loadtxt` will be able to read the file `data1.dat` without passing any extra parameters.

Comment: @n1colas.m It has worked. Thanks a lot. I'd be grateful if you could further suggest some good references to study on such kind of data processing and data handling. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use column_stack from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = [0.11, 2.15, 0.39, 5.79, 6.53]
y = [99.2, -0.32, -12.95, -2.5, -7.5]

df = np.column_stack((x,y))

np.savetxt('data1.dat', df, header = ' x, y ')
```

Later, your data should look like you want.
Then it's easy to read with:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data1.dat', unpack=True)
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
```

Good luck!